# One sample t-test multiple testing

Tags: t-test

I have written a script that computes a list of values (based on some parameters). Now, I executed the script for different parameters1. And for each value, I did it 5 times.

5 times param1 = 10; 
5 times param1 = 100;
....

On each of these datasets, I performed a one sample t-test (so H0: mean = X, H1: mean < X). Thus, I have results like this:
For param1 = 10: 5 out of 5 H0 accepted
For param1 = 100: 1 out of 5 H0 accepted
...

Now I would want for each parameter1 only 1 value: accepted or rejected.
Can I say that I accept the null hypothesis if for example more than half of H0's are accepted (So in this example, for param1 = 10 it would be accepted, while it would be rejected for param1 = 100), or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you only care about each value of the parameter separately; that is to say, you want to make separate inferences for each instance of the parameter, and that the overall Type I error control across the families of hypotheses corresponding to each instance of the parameter does **not** need to be maintained.  Rather, you want some Type I error control over each family comprising the five tests at a given value of the parameter.

You have already intuitively recognized that if each $t$-test of one of the five samples is conducted at, say, level $\alpha$, then the probability that at least one of these null hypotheses is rejected erroneously (i.e. the test rejects $H_0$ when $H_0$ is true), is substantially greater than $\alpha$--this is the multiplicity problem.  Specifically, for five independent samples, the familywise Type I error is as large as $1 - (1-\alpha)^5$.  For $\alpha = 0.05$ for a single test, this would inflate the familywise error to over $0.22$.

However, what has not been discussed above is that the overall conclusion need not be that $H_a$ is true if only one hypothesis in the family is rejected--if, for example, you decide that to reject the familywise null hypothesis one must reject $H_0$ for **each** of the five tests, then clearly you have no multiplicity issue, and your type I error is actually tiny:  the chance of rejecting $H_0$ (familywise) when $H_0$ is true becomes $\alpha^5$, and for $\alpha = 0.05$ this is $3.125 \times 10^{-7}$.

In between these two extremes, one might use the intuitive criterion that at at least 3 out of 5 tests must reject $H_0$.  What would be the familywise Type I error in this case?  I leave this question to the reader as an exercise.

That said, none of the above addresses the **power** under these scenarios, or even the more fundamental question of the choice of $\alpha$ for a single test to begin with; neither of which were mentioned in your question.

Comment: As an aside, I just want to state for the record that the phrase "$H_0$ accepted" is abhorrent and must never be used.  The notion that a frequentist test could ever provide statistical evidence that the null hypothesis is true, when the distribution of the test statistic is **conditional on the null being true** is an affront to statistical practice.